# How to filter out the data by date using DFSORT

Tags: timestamp, mainframe, dfsort

I have a flat file with some useful data along with `timestamp` on each record. Inorder to create a report, I need data of last month ONLY for my further analysis. With out using a cobol source code, REXX EXECs I need to filter out last month's data using DFSORT. Hope my question is clear.

***Note:** I use JOBTRAC scheduler. Using JOBTRAC parameters, I can dynamically allocate values and filter out data, but dont want to make use of them.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible answer:

```
//STEP01  EXEC PGM=SORT,REGION=0M
//SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*
//SORTIN    DD DSN=INPUT.DATASET,DISP=SHR
//SORTOUT   DD DSN=OUTPUT.DATASET,DISP=NEW
//SYSIN     DD *
   INCLUDE COND=(001,007,EQ,DATE2(-)-1)
/*
```

I have assumed the following things:

1. The timestamp starts at position one
2. The timestamp is an alphanumeric
3. The timestamp starts with YYYY-MM-DD
4. "Last month" is the month previous to the current one

Comment: But this sort card doesnt result in same set of records during the month. I would like to have a SORT card which should result in same set of records even it is run at the end of next month. Hope i made clear my requirement. Thanks for your time!

Comment: To run, this requires OPTION COPY, or a SORT statement or a MERGE statement.